# HTML In Listview

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to show list of post titles coming from wordpress. The titles have unicode characters in them. Like this `&#8220;I Shall Not Forget&#8221;` I want it to show “I Shall Not Forget”

In code behind `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(text.Title.Rendered)` will take care of it. Can I do that somehow in the XAMAL?

```
    <ListView x:Name="postList" ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label FormattedText="{Binding Title.Rendered}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: use a ValueConverter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code based on what @Jason said: Using a converter.

Create a class called HtmlConverter:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace StackoverflowQ.Converters
{
    public class HtmlConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region Converter

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                string text = (string)value;
                return System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(text);
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

In your xaml reference that class (Mine is in a **folder** called Converters)

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:StackoverflowQ.Converters;assembly=StackoverflowQ"
```

Then add it in your **ResourceDictionary** from there you should be able to reference it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="StackoverflowQ.Views.MainPage" 
    Title="{Binding Title}">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary> 
            <converters:HtmlConverter x:Key="HtmlConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"> 

    <ListView x:Name="postList" ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label  Text="{Binding Title.Rendered , Converter={StaticResource HtmlConverter}}"  />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>


    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thank you @LeRoy ! This is perfect. I have used converters before to calculate UI component sizes but never thought of using one for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Label Renderer to convert HTML text like this:

CustomLabel:

```
public class CustomLabel: Label
{
}
```

Android Renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomLabel), typeof(HtmlFormattedLabelRenderer))]
 namespace XYZ.Droid.Renderer
{
  public class HtmlFormattedLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
   {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var view = (CustomLabel)Element;
        if (view == null) return;
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Control.Text))
          Control.SetText(Html.FromHtml(view.Text.ToString()), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
    }
  }
}
```

iOS Renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomLabel), typeof(HtmlFormattedLabelRendereriOS))]
namespace XYZ.iOS.Renderer
{
  public class HtmlFormattedLabelRendereriOS:LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var view = (CustomLabel)Element;
        if (view == null) return;

        var attr = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes();
        var nsError = new NSError();
        attr.DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML;

        Control.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(view.Text, attr, ref nsError);

        var mutable = Control.AttributedText as NSMutableAttributedString;
        UIStringAttributes uiString = new UIStringAttributes();
        uiString.Font = UIFont.FromName("Roboto-Regular",15f);
        uiString.ForegroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(130, 130, 130);
        mutable.SetAttributes(uiString, new NSRange(0, Control.Text.Length));
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The HtmlText property of Forms9Patch.Label decodes escapes. Forms9Patch is a free, open source (MIT License) NuGet package.  Full disclosure:  I am the author of Forms9Patch.